# Как сделать чтобы при запуске проекта открывался другой url?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Всем привет! Столкнулся с проблемой, что не знаю как правильно открыть правильный url при самом первом запуске проекта. Нужно чтобы при запуске, например, открывался http://localhost:3000/projects... Буду очень благодарен за помощь! (вроде можно сделать это через useEffect, но оно просто багует)

Comment: Что значит "при самом первом запуске проекта"? Проект же не запускается сам собой, а пользователь открывает ссылку в браузере. Какую введёт в адресную строку, такая и откроется.

Comment: Вообще, исходя из того, что я досочинил к вашему вопросу, я бы добавил в router правило для `/`, открывающее специальный компонент, который через componentDidMount переадресовывает браузер на `/project`.

Comment: @mymedia, вы не правы, при `npm run starrt` в брауезере сама открывается ссылка.

Comment: @OliverPatterson, по этой команде NPM запускает сценарий starrt из package.json файла. Эта команда может делать всё что угодно. Но её возможно настроить.

Comment: @mymedia, вот автор и спрашивает, как открыть другую ссылку при `npm run start`, а не `/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Укажите в `package.json` свойство `"homepage": "/projects"`.